# Different attribute order in XML printed file

Tags: java, xml, printing, jaxb

Is there a reason why the same Java code will produce XML files with different order of the element attributes? My guess would be different JVM, but if so how can I predict which order it will produce?

Some more details: I'm using `JAXB` XML binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that the attributes are being kept internally in a hash table of some kind, with the attribute name used as a key. It's a characteristic of hash tables that they don't retain order. With many hashing algorithms the order will be consistent even though it isn't predictable, but sometimes it can depend on pseudo-random factors such as where the next chunk of free memory is found.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds right. I got the difference in order on the same machine a few days later.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a reason why the same Java code will produce XML files with
>   different order of the element attributes?

Because the [XML spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-attr) that the order of the attributes doesn't matter.

Attributes are key-value pairs that serve the purpose of clarify the features of the element. Their order has no effect to the document structure, unlike the order of elements.

Comment: Yes but there is some order in which they are printed, right? My experience is that on the same machine the order is always the same. But on different machines it is different. I'm not interested in the way the attributes are ordered, but in how to keep it always the same.

Comment: Of course the serialized form has some order (nobody likes overlapping characters ;) But after the XML is parsed, and before it is serialized - whenever XML is handled as a tree (DOM, object, etc) - the whole concept of "order" between attributes does not exist. So the perceived order can change. It is like saying "in what order are those apples in that bowl?" The order doesn't appear until you pick them out of the bowl and put them in a line on a table. Also you are allowed to pick them and put them back in any order, which is another way of saying that it is "implementation defined".

Comment: Maintaining the string representation of an XML document usually is not only unnecessary, but on the contrary, requiring it hints that you are not really handling XML as XML, or with XML tools. However if the serialization format is significant for some reason, then you should read up on canonical XML. The purpose of canonicalization is to normalize away minor differences that shouldn't affect the XML. One such feature is that in canonical XML the attributes should always be outputted in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

Different input.  If it is truly the exact same Java code, then what might varying is the inputs.  I'd be surprised if the reason a different JVM.

I really need to know more to give you a better answer than that.

Comment: I copied the same program and the same input on another machine and it shifted some of the attributes around, but it kept to one pattern, i.e. on PC1 a=1 b=1 c=1, on PC2 b=1 a=1 c=1 in all elements containing them.